# Can't connect to cassandra, authentication error, please carefully check your auth settings, retrying soon

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

Stuck with the below error while configuring dse address.yaml.

```
INFO [async-dispatch-1] 2021-04-17 07:50:06,487 Starting DynamicEnvironmentComponent
 ;;;;;
 ;;;;;
 INFO [async-dispatch-1] 2021-04-17 07:50:06,503 Starting monitored database connection.
 ERROR [async-dispatch-1] 2021-04-17 07:50:08,717 Can't connect to Cassandra, authentication error, please carefully check your Auth settings, retrying soon.
 INFO [async-dispatch-1] 2021-04-17 07:50:08,720 Finished starting system.
```

Configured cassandra user and password in cluster-name.conf & address.yaml as well.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've provided very little information about the issue you're running into so our ability to assist you is very limited.

In any case, my suspicion is that (a) you haven't configured the correct `seed_hosts` in `cluster_name.conf`, or (b) the seeds are unreachable from the agents.

If this is your first time installing OpsCenter, I highly recommend that you let OpsCenter install and configure the agents automatically. When you add the cluster to OpsCenter, you will get prompted with a choice on whether to do this automatically:

[image]

For details, see [Installing DataStax Agents automatically](https://docs.datastax.com/en/install/6.8/install/automaticInstallationAgents.html).

As a side note, we don't recommend you set any properties in `address.yaml` unless it's a last resort. Wherever possible and in almost all cases, configure the agent properties in `cluster_name.conf` so it's managed centrally instead of individual nodes.

It's difficult to help you troubleshoot your problem in a Q&A forum. If you're still experiencing issues, my suggestion is to log a **[DataStax Support](https://support.datastax.com/)** ticket so one of our engineers can assist you directly. Cheers!